# Retorno de funções async

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, async

Estou usando o `AsyncStorage` para salvar o valor de alguns `tokens` com o seguinte código:

AsyncStorage.js:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

setValue = async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  console.log('value set')
}

getMyValue = async (key) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    console.log(value)
    return value
  } catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

App.js:

```
import store from './AsyncStorage'
const str = new store
setValue('1', 'teste')
console.log(getMyValue('1'))
```

Só que o return da função está acontecendo antes do await retornar com os dados, pois no console do react native está na seguinte ordem:

```
//essa linha é do console.log(getMyValue('1'))
LOG  {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}
LOG  value set  // essa é o console.log('value set')   
LOG teste // essa é o console.log(value)
```

Tentei dar o return logo na hora de executar o AsyncStorage.getItem(key) assim:

```
return await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
```

Porém da o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri o que estava acontecendo:

No arquivo `AsyncStorage.js` eu tinha a função `async` com `await` do retorno do `storage`, porém no arquivo App.js eu tinha uma atribuição sincrona, ou seja, ele realizava a atribuição antes de a função `getMyValue` pudesse retornar com o valor do "value"

Para corrigir o problema eu criei uma função assíncrona na atribuição também, da seguinte forma:

```
str.setValue('1', '2')
const f = async () => {
  console.log(await str.getMyValue('1'))
}
```

O único problema é que toda a manipulação desse dado vai ter que ser feita dentro da função async, visto que se você retornar a função da seguinte forma:

```
str.setValue('1', '2')
const f = async () => {
  return await str.getMyValue('1'))
}
console.log(f())
```

Ele vai gerar o mesmo problema, pois a atribuição está fora do assincronismo.